# cURL scraping functions

Tags: php

Can you enlighten me with your knowledge about cURL? I tried cURL but the output of the function is it copies the whole site. I plan to just gather all the search results of that site.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the format of the page you are retrieving is HTML or XML; please look at this answer for good ways in PHP to parse an HTML/XML page: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Beware that some HTML pages might be dynamic, using JavaScript to build the actual result page, maybe even doing so in ajax. The static html/xml page you get with cURL might not contain the information you want!

Comment: Was looking for the answer that link's the question above, +1